# Why authors name go out side the column in IEEE latex format?

Tags: titles, ieeetran, affiliation

I am using the following format to 6 authors to a paper that uses IEEE conference format. But the names is going outside the allowed width of the column. I do not know what the reason is but there are some authors whose names are long. Any possible solution since this problem does not allow and to accept the paper.

Here is code:

```
\author{Ibrahim~ Aaronjacob\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},~~Raza\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},~Ibrahim~Abdallah \IEEEauthorrefmark{4},~ Aaronjacob~Abdallah\IEEEauthorrefmark{3},~ Ibrahim~Abdallah\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},~ Aaronjacob~Abdallah\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}  \\ \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, USA}
        \\\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Division of Information and Computing Technology}\\    
        \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science, USA}\\    
     }
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\` to spread out the authors across multiple lines. Also don't overuse the ties `~`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{A title}
\author{%
  Ibrahim~Aaronjacob\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
  Raza\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
  Ibrahim~Abdallah\IEEEauthorrefmark{4},
  Aaronjacob~Abdallah\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, \\
  Ibrahim~Abdallah\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
  Aaronjacob~Abdallah\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}
  \\
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Department of Electrical and Computer Engineering, USA
  }
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Division of Information and Computing Technology
  }
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science, USA
  }
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```